# Angular2(ES5) HashLocationstartergy error

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I want to use Hashlocationstartergy for routing in angular2 using ES5. My code snipped for bootstratpping main.js is below:

```
(function(app) {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

        ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(app.AppComponent, [
                ng.router.ROUTER_PROVIDERS, ,
                ng.core.provide(ng.common.LocationStrategy, {
                    useClass : ng.common.HashLocationStrategy
                }) ]);
    });

})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

I am getting below error while running it:

```
uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getOptional' of undefined on application_ref.ts:289
```

Note: I have added angular2-all.umd.dev.js,Rx.umd.js,shims_for_IE.js,angular2-polyfills.js scripts in html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is located here:

```
 ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(app.AppComponent, [
    ng.router.ROUTER_PROVIDERS, , <== undefined array item
```

Comment: Thanks! actual issue was LocationStrategy and HashLocationStrategy are under  ng.router so actual code should be 

ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(app.AppComponent, [
    ng.router.ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    ng.core.provide(ng.router.LocationStrategy, {
     useClass : ng.router.HashLocationStrategy
    }) ]);

Comment: Hi chikka.anddev, do you know which version works with ng.router.HashLocationStrategy? I can't seem to get it work in beta17 (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.17/angular2-all.umd.dev.js). Thanks.